# GLS ShipIT Rest API not responding on production server

Tags: php, rest, curl

Good morning yall.
We are currently implementing the GLS ShipIT Rest API into our Webshop.
We contacted GLS to get the live API data and tried sending it to it.
When sending the request from our local machines everything worked like a charm and a shipping label has been created.
However, when we run the same request from our production server we don´t get any answer.
Until yesterday we got a Connection Refused which has been solved by opening the required port for GLS. But when we now send the request to their servers we don't get back any answers at all.

We got into contact with GLS and showed them our request which was perfectly fine. Obviously, I guess because it works like a charm on our local machines.

We use CURL and PHP to send out the POST request to there API. Maybe anyone has some idea on why our production server seems to have problems with the request and our test servers don't.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $this->sUrl.'rs/shipments',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    URLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $sJson,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
         $sAuth,
         'Accept: application/glsVersion1+json, application/json',
         'Content-Type: application/glsVersion1+json'
          ],
      ]);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

$sAuth is the required authentication header.
$sJson is the content of the POST request including the data required by GLS to create a label.

Maybe someone had something similar happening to them and could help me with this.

Things we already tried:

1. Opening the required ports
2. Getting in contact with GLS to check if the POST request is correct or not
3. Checking if our server is blacklisted for there api